# Create a dictionary with input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from user input, with the ability to add nested dictionaries as well.
The code I have now can create a dictionary, with one level nesting, but I think there's a better way to do this and also make the nesting levels be unlimited, does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
def input_to_dict():
    def str_or_list(value):
        # return list if values are separated by comma, else return string
        if "," in value:
            value = value.split(",")
            value = [i.strip() for i in value]
            return value
        else:
            return value.strip()
    
    temp_dict = {}
    while True:
        key = input('Key: ').title()
        if not key:
            break
        value = input('Value: ')
        # if value is key-value pair, nest dict
        if ":" in value:
            value = value.split(":")
            value_k = value[0].strip().title()
            value_v = value[1].strip()
            temp_dict[key] = {value_k: str_or_list(value_v)}
            
        else:
            temp_dict[key] = str_or_list(value)
        
    return temp_dict
```

Comment: What kind of input would create nested dictionaries? I suspect your input format doesn't handle this unambiguously -- you need some way to delimit the nested data.

Comment: This is the kind of problem that formats like JSON solve.

Comment: I don't have a specific output, I'm looking for a way to create a dict with input only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the nested dictionaries to be able to include arbitrary entries, including more nested dictionaries, you probably want a recursive function, e.g.:

```
def input_to_dict():
    d = {}
    while True:
        k = input('Key: ').title()
        if not k:
            break
        v = input('Value: ')
        if v == ":":
            d[k] = input_to_dict()
        elif "," in v:
            d[k] = [i.strip() for i in v]
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

```
Key: foo
Value: bar
Key: moar
Value: :
Key: foo
Value: bar
Key: moar
Value: :
Key: foo
Value: bar
Key:
Key:
Key:
{'Foo': 'bar', 'Moar': {'Foo': 'bar', 'Moar': {'Foo': 'bar'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using thanks to @Samwise answer  
I added indentation and cleaned console text a little for clarity, and I also added an option to only use keys from a ref dict.

```
def input_to_dict(nest=0, ref=None):
    # indentation for nested dictionaries
    indent = "    " * nest if nest > 0 else ""
    
    # return list if values are separated by comma, else return string
    def islist(value):
        if "," in value:
            value = value.split(",")
            value = [i.strip() for i in value]
            return value
        else:
            return value.strip()
    
    def clear_line():
        print("\033[F", end="") # Move up one line
        print("\033[K", end="") # Clear line
    
    d = {}
    while True:
        k = input(f'{indent}Key: ').title()
        clear_line()
        if not k:
            break
        if ref and k not in ref.keys():
            clear_line()
            print("Invalid key! choose from:", ", ".join(ref))
            continue
        
        v = input(f'{indent}{k}: ')
        if v == ":" or v == "\t":
            clear_line()
            print(f'{indent}{k}:')
            if ref:
                d[k] = input_to_dict(nest + 1, ref[k])
            else:
                d[k] = input_to_dict(nest + 1)
        else:
            d[k] = islist(v)
    return d
```